# C# COM Server and Client fails with InvalidCastException

Tags: c#, server, com, client

This is the C# Com Server (Registered with Regasm):

```
[ComVisible(true), Guid("565D8202-6C0F-4AAB-B0F6-49719CD13045"),
InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsDual)]
public interface ITestObject
{
    void DoSomething();
}

[ComVisible(true), GuidAttribute("21293767-A713-49E2-968E-7DDE0B0DAB94"),
    ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)
]
public class TestObject : ITestObject
{
    public void DoSomething()
    {
    }
}
```

---

And this is the C# COM client:

```
[ComImport(), Guid("565D8202-6C0F-4AAB-B0F6-49719CD13045"),
    InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
public interface ITestObject
{
    [PreserveSig]
    void DoSomething();
}
```

And here is the problem:

```
Type type = Type.GetTypeFromCLSID(new Guid("21293767-A713-49E2-968E-7DDE0B0DAB94"));
object o = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
ITestObject t = (ITestObject)o;
```

The cast to ITestObject fails with an InvalidCastException. But it is possible to call the method DoSomething() as a dynamic C# object.

Does anyone have an idea how to solve the InvalidCastException?

Comment: You know you have different interface types? One is Dual and other is IUnknown? in COM, a Dual interface is derived from IDispatch not IUnknown.

Comment: Oh yeah, thats a small mistake. Even if both values are Dual or IUnknown - this results in the same error.